# Can't get array to pass to another page using PHP

Tags: php, simplexml, session-variables

I am a newcomer to programming and PHP and am having trouble passing an array with simplexml elements between two pages.

```
Array
(
[price] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 290.4
    )

[Currency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => USD
    )
```

I can get the  information into the session as I can echo it out on the first page but when I try to echo it on the second page the array appears to be empty.

First page

```
$_SESSION['selectedInfo'] = $selectedInfo;
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Second page

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>"; 

?>
```

The result

```
Array
(
)
```

I have searched and found many ways to convert from simplexml to array but none of them seem to work. I  would really appreciate if anyone had a solution

Comment: Did you check whether your session handler is configured properly and you’re using the same session on both pages?

Comment: use php's `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to pass the value

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `serialize` function like this :

```
 $_SESSION['foo'] = serialize($array);
```

Then on the other page you `unserialize` it :

```
 $array = unserialize($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Comment: This is the way to solve this problem. The problem the OP is having is that the array contains objects and not arrays. `serialize()` will allow you to store objects, as long as the class they belong to exists in the script when you call `unserialize()`

Comment: Right, I had forgotten to tell that the class should exist in current scope when unserializing.

Answer (score 0):

look up php's implode function to 'compress' the array, then you can store it in a 'hidden' form field then you can $_POST that to the next page. That's what I have done before. Once you get the compressed version of the array in the second page, you can explode it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you can't serialize objects of class `SimpleXMLElement` (session data is serialized)
Example:

```
serialize(new SimpleXMLElement("<test><x>z</x></test>"));


PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in /home/riad/Рабочий стол/1.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/riad/Рабочий стол/1.php(11): serialize(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /path on line 11
```

It should be possible to use something like

```
class SimpleXMLElementArray extends ArrayIterator{
    public function __sleep(){
        foreach($this as $k=>$v){
            $this[$k] = $v->asXML();
        }
    }
    public function __wakeup(){
            foreach($this as $k=>$v){
                $this[$k]=new SimpleXMLElemt($v);
        }
 }
 SimpleXMLElementArray($your_array);
```

But by some reasons it throw this exception too if you not use `__sleep` manually

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I tried some of your suggestions but still could not get it to work. Iltimately I solved my probem by turning eack element to a string while adding it to the array.    `$array[  ] = array( 'element1'=>(string)$var1, 'element2'=>(string)$var2, 'element3'=>(string)$var3);` I was then able to pass the array in a session.